# How to create multiple row header and merge it with other columns in GridView devexpress

Tags: c#, devexpress

How to create multiple row header and merge it with other columns in GridView 
Devexpress like on the image below:

[image: sample image]

Comment: Are you using Desktop or Web versions of the DX GridView?

Comment: I am using Desktop winform.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the [Banded Grid View](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3467/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/View-Technology/Banded-Grid-Views/Banded-Grid-View) to displays data in a two-dimensional table while organizing columns in [bands](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/801/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/View-Technology/Banded-Grid-Views/Bands-Overview):
[image: banded grid view]
If you want your data row's cells to be arranged one under another and to have different heights, you should use the [Advanced Banded Grid View](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3468/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/View-Technology/Banded-Grid-Views/Advanced-Banded-Grid-View).
[image: advanced banded grid view]

To learn more please start reading from the [Banded Grid Views](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/114637/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/View-Technology/Banded-Grid-Views) documentation articles.